# What is the purpose of DELETED Table in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So far, i know that:

1. There is a `Table` called `DELETED` in my MSSQL Database.
2. I have not created that `Table` which means it already existed.

> Is there a similar Table called UPDATED?

Comment: Do you mean `MSSQL` ?

Comment: [**Read the documentation - "Use the inserted and deleted Tables"**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables), it has all you need to know.

Comment: yes im sorry ill edit my qeustion

Comment: Did you see that in database or in `Trigger` script ?

Comment: yes , in a Trigger script

Comment: @Phill - You got the answer below and it is very basic feature of trigger in MSSQL

Answer (score 6):

There is not a `deleted` table in SQL Server. There are "logical tables" (I think of them more like views, but the implementation is not important) called `deleted` and `inserted` that are available in triggers and other operations that alter data in tables.

An `update` trigger defines both of them.

This is pretty well explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables).

Comment: Not only in triggers but also in INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE statements when coupled with an OUTPUT clause.

Answer (score 0):

you can see example of using DELETED and INSERTED logical tables in the MERGE statement:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql